# How to use aop.js with jQuery on Grouped Lists?

Tags: jquery

This question came from following up on an [answer given here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16407/how-to-make-grouped-view-work-with-the-document-ready-event).

I want to use jQuery to work css modifications on a list that has grouping.  [I discovered](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16407/how-to-make-grouped-view-work-with-the-document-ready-event) a [jQuery script called `aop.js`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/) that will allow you to attach function calls onto other functions.  There is [another page here](http://www.sharepoint-howto.com/2011/12/20/sharepoint-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-with-jquery/#comment-14622) with more explanation.  And so, I came up with this, where I attach a function call onto `ExpGroupRenderData` so that I can run a function AFTER the list items are grouped.

```
jQuery.aop.around( {target: window, method: 'ExpGroupRenderData'},
    function (invocation) {
    //alert("args2=" + invocation.arguments[2] ");
        if (invocation.arguments[2] == 'true') { //check to see if html loaded
            var group = "#tbod"+invocation.arguments[1]+"_";    //the invocation gets the main groupname, something like tbod40-2_, but we add a "_" for the one we are searching for
            var maindiv = jQuery('#pagebody').get(0);               
            jQuery.data(maindiv, "group", group); //write data to div
        }
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
);  


//https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54186/how-to-use-aop-js-with-jquery-on-grouped-lists
jQuery.aop.after( {target: window, method: 'ExpGroupRenderData'}, 
    function(result) { 
        var maindiv = jQuery('#pagebody').get(0);
        var group = jQuery.data(maindiv, "group");
        if(group){
            setRatingsStyles();
            alert("found group" );
            jQuery.data(maindiv, "group", ""); //clear out data
        }
        return result;
    } 
);
```

**[update]**

...snip snip...

Using the code from [this page](http://www.sharepoint-howto.com/2011/12/20/sharepoint-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-with-jquery/#comment-14622), if I remove the `if (invocation.arguments[2] == 'true')` test, the function will, indeed, fire, but it only runs on a group that has already been expanded at least once.  (Now the styling works fine; I have a [post on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898356/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-and-replace-a-class-based-on-its-contained-text/13898418#13898418)).

_(just a note - you could use any div to store the jquery data property.  #pagebody is in my custom master page. I couldn't find a #MSO_ContentTable in my outputted code; but it stores the data just fine)_

The effect is that when the user expands a group, it does not get styled.  But if he expands a second group, the previous group gets styled, even if that group has been contracted.

If I leave the `if` clause, nothing ever happens. If I uncomment the `alert` in the `around` function, then I can see that the `invocation.arguments[2]` (which is the `isLoaded` property of the `ExpGroupRenderData` function) is always false when the `around` function checks it.

It seems like the `aop.around` function does not wait long enough to check the value of `isLoaded`.

I have been stuck on this for days.  Can anyone make a suggestion?

**[update]**

This seems to work a *little* bit better.  At least it works now on the just-opened group if I open it, close it, and open it again.  That is one bit better, at least.

```
jQuery.aop.after( {target: window, method: 'ExpCollGroup'}, //notice the method
    function() { 
        setRatingsStyles();
    } 
);
```

Comment: @Colin - I hope you haven't forgotten me from http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16407/how-to-make-grouped-view-work-with-the-document-ready-event !

Comment: Methinks that nobody else uses aop.js, at least, not with Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after much hassle and striving, I came up with this which seems to work pretty well, although I hate to use such a mechanism:

```
$jq.aop.around( {target: window, method: 'ExpGroupRenderData'},
    function (invocation) {
    setTimeout('setRatingsStyles()',250);
    }
);
```

I needed to wait just a wee bit on the `aop.around` function.  Turns out that I don't even need the `aop.after` if I do it this way.  The user sees the syling take effect, however.

Comment: If noone has a better answer, I'm going to mark my thread solved by me.